# Why does Insertion Sort not need the swap operation?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, swap

So I am currently learning Java and I was asking myself, why the Insertion-Sort method doesn´t have the need to use the swap operation? As Far as I understood, elements get swapped so wouldn´t it be usefull to use the swap operation in this sorting algorithm?

As I said, I am new to this but I try to understand the background of these algorithms , why they are the way they actually are

Would be happy for some insights :)
B.

Comment: Have you gone through the source with a debugger to verify that it doesn't use any kind of a swap operation? Can you paste the code here?

Comment: Can you provide code? Or, what are you asking?

Comment: You may be thinking of a *selection sort*, which runs through the unsorted portion of the list, finds the smallest remaining element, and then swaps it into place.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia's [article for Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) states

> Each iteration, insertion sort removes one element from the input
>   data, finds the location it belongs within the sorted list, and
>   inserts it there. It repeats until no input elements remain. [...]  If
>   smaller, it finds the correct position within the sorted list, **shifts
>   all the larger values up to make a space, and inserts into that
>   correct position.**

You can consider this shift as an extreme swap. What actually happens is the value is stored in a placeholder and checked versus the other values. If those values are smaller, they are simply shifted, ie. replace the previous (or next) position in the list/array. The placeholder's value is then put in the position from which the element was shifted.

Comment: I can't see how the shifting would be implemented efficiently if not in terms of a lot of swap operations.

Comment: @Marko You don't need to swap, you just overwrite the element in the previous or next position (depending on the direction). Your value is stored in a placeholder so you don't lose it. When you are done shifting, you place the value in the placeholder in the latest processed index.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion Sort does not perform swapping. It performs insertions by shifting elements in a sequential list to make room for the element that is being inserted.

That is why it is an O(N^2) algorithm: for each element out of N, there can be O(N) shifts.

Answer (score 0):

So, you Could do insertion sort by swapping.
But, is that the best way to do it? you should think of what a swap is...

```
   temp = a
   a=b
   b=temp
```

there are 3 assignments that take place for a single swap.

eg. [2,3,1]
If the above list is to be sorted, you could 1. swap 3 and 1 then, 2. swap 1 and 2
total 6 assignments

Now,
Instead of swapping, if you just shift 2 and 3 one place to the right ( 1 assignment each) and then put 1 in array[0], you would end up with just 3 assignments instead of the 6 you would do with swapping.